# WP query_posts by category number

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I'm trying to set up query_posts to display some "products" on a page, but cannot get the sorting to work how I would like.

I have these for categories:

Products(13)

- F Series (12)
- Z Series (14)
- R Series (15)
- K Series (16)

I would like to order the posts by the child category number first, and then by title. So I need all the "F Series" listed first sorted alphabetically, then all the "Z series" sorted alphabetically, etc.

So far I've only managed to get them all alphabetical (so R series comes before Z series), or they come in based on the date I added them (which doesn't work if I need to add a F Series after I've added all the previous items).

I've thought of just using multiple loops, but my client doesn't know php, and won't be able to add the code for a new loop if he wants to add another category.

Any help is appreciated. I can't seem to orderby the child category value...

I've tried so many things, it's hard to remember what didn't work:

```
query_posts("cat=13&orderby=category,title&order=ASC");
query_posts("cat=13&orderby=meta_key_num,title&order=ASC");
query_posts("cat=13&orderby=parent menu_item&order=ASC");

<?php $categories = get_categories("child_of=17");
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
query_posts("cat=$cat->cat_ID&showposts=-1&order=ASC&orderby=title");
```

Comment: can you post your code - what you've tried already?

Comment: You'll need an array of arrays during "the loop". Sort the inner arrays, sort the outer arrays, print them. This should be dynamic and not need your client's interaction.

Comment: Mark - it's hard to know what I have and haven't tried so far, I posted the ones I can remember above and updated my question.

Comment: You can use `in_category` instead of `cat`

Comment: If youre using Objects, dont use `"cat=$cat->cat_ID"`, use `""cat=" . $cat->cat_ID . "..."` or `"cat={$cat->cat_ID}"`

Comment: [You really should be using WP_Query.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: @KerynGill you want to display them as posts or as a list?

Comment: Posts? I guess it doesn't really matter. Right now I've been looping, and then using the_title(); and wrapping that in a title tag, same goes for featured image, and content, etc, just so I can format it the way I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will list your category name (just so you can see what its doing) sorted by the category ID as well as each post link posted in that category

```
<?php $parentcat = get_category('13'); 
$args = array('parent'  => $parentcat->term_id, 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=> '-1');  
$categories = get_categories( $args); 
foreach ($categories as $category){
$catID = $category->term_id ;
echo $category->slug.'<br />';
$argsb = array('category__in'  => $catID, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=> '-1');  
$posts = get_posts($argsb);
foreach ($posts as $post){setup_postdata($post);?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php } };?>
```

Comment: I tried this method, but all it does it organize them alphabetically, which I don't want. I want it organized by child category, and then alphabetically.

Comment: how do you want the child categories ordered?

Comment: by the "number" or "id". So F series has an ID of 12, so I want all those first, sorted "abc", then Z series comes next with id of 14, so I want all the z series listed by abc, after all the f series, etc.
I'm just stumped on how to sort the child categories.

Comment: @KerynGill I think I understood what you want - I updated my answer

Comment: Worked like a charm Mike!! I realized after I needed to sort by a custom field rather than title, but I just used the meta_key_num, instead of title with your code and it works great!!!! Thanks so much!!